# Where can I find a schematic of the AT&T KBD 301?

Tags: hardware, debugging, hardware-testing

Where can I find a schematic of the AT&T KBD 301?

I have an old AT&T 6300 (AT&T's rebrand of the Olivetti M24) but the keyboard (AT&T KBD 301) is not working.

Many of the keys do work when I press them.  But some of the keys either don't produce a character, or they produce the wrong character.  I know the keyboard worked back in 2007 before it got put it in storage.

I opened the keyboard and tried cleaning the electrical contacts beneath the keys with some alcohol, but the problem is still there.

I want to try and diagnose what the problem is specifically.  It would be really useful to find a schematic rather than having to reverse engineer one myself.

Once I know how it works I can either try and repair it or make a replacement keyboard.

I could see a cheap microcontroller running some custom code acting as a translator for a USB keyboard as being a reasonable solution.